# Spring data mongo bulk update

Tags: mongotemplate

Bulk updates are supported from spring-data-mongodb from 1.9.0.RELEASE.

```
BulkOperations ops = template.bulkOps(BulkMode.UNORDERED, Match.class);
for (User user : users) {
    Update update = new Update();
    ...
    ops.updateOne(query(where("id").is(user.getId())), update);
}
ops.execute();
```

mongoTemplate has the function called void save(Object objectToSave); I want to insert/update the whole record but not some particular fields. Is there any way or function that I can void the Update class?

Maybe something like this..?

```
BulkOperations ops = template.bulkOps(BulkMode.UNORDERED, Match.class);
for (User user : users) {
    ...
    ops.save(query(where("id").is(user.getId())), user);
}
ops.execute();
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the ***upsert(Query query, Object object)*** it is not supported in the Spring Data MongoDB bulk operations.

However we can use **Update.fromDBObject** method to generate an **Update** object from a **DBObject**:

```
    BulkOperations bulkOps = mongoOperations.bulkOps(BulkOperations.BulkMode.ORDERED, entityInformation.getJavaType()); 

    // add "save" operation for each entity
    MongoConverter converter = mongoOperations.getConverter();
    ConversionService conversionService = converter.getConversionService();
    com.mongodb.DBObject dbObject;
    for (S entity : entities) {
        if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) { // --- if NEW entity, then generate id and INSERT ---

            // generate NEW id
            ID id = conversionService.convert(new ObjectId(), entityInformation.getIdType());                
            entity.setId(id);
            // insert
            bulkOps.insert(entity);

        } else { // --- if EXISTING entity, then UPSERT ---

            // convert entity to mongo DBObject
            dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
            // NULL fields will NOT BE UPDATED - will be ignored when converting an entity to a {@link com.mongodb.DBObject} 
            // and thus they will not be added to the {@link Update} statement.
            converter.write(entity, dbObject);                
            // upsert
            bulkOps.upsert(new Query(Criteria.where(UNDERSCORE_ID).is(dbObject.get(UNDERSCORE_ID))),
                           Update.fromDBObject(new BasicDBObject("$set", dbObject)));
        }
    }
    // execute bulk operations
    bulkOps.execute();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
BulkOperations ops = mongoOps.bulkOps(BulkMode.<ordered/unordered>,<your ob>.class);
loop on your batch {
    Update update = Update.fromDBObject(
        BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$set", <your ob>).get()
    );
    ops.upsert(query(where("").is(<your ob>.something())), update);
}
ops.execute();
```

This will update entire pojo(not some particular fields) just like save.

Answer (score 0):

org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate provides the implementation of BulkWriteOperation. You can use it.

```
BulkWriteOperation bulkWriteOperation= mongoTemplate.getCollection(collectionName).initializeUnorderedBulkOperation();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    BulkOperations bulkOperations = mongoTemplate.bulkOps(BulkOperations.BulkMode.UNORDERED, "someCollection");
    bulkOperations.insert(addressRanges);
    bulkOperations.execute();
```

This is all you need.

Answer (score -2):

Delete and insert will be the option you can opt for but you need to take back up of your data before you choose this options in case of any failures.

Comment: Terrible idea. Very easy to end up in an inconsistent state.